# Matplotlib Animation showing up empty

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

There was a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26544488/python-animation-x-y-coordinates-along-time) but I'm not having the same issue. Below is a snapshot of my dataset:

[image]

Essentially, I'd like to animate the drop off coordinates over time. As you can see the dates are sorted by `dropoff_datetime`. Here is my code (very similar to the question above).

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = plt.axes(xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim)
points, = ax.plot([], [],'.',alpha = 0.4, markersize = 0.05)

def init():
    points.set_data([], [])
    return points,

# animation function.  This is called sequentially
def animate(i):
    x = test["dropoff_longitude"]
    y = test["dropoff_latitude"]
    points.set_data(x, y)
    return points,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=100, interval=20, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Similar to the issue in the problem linked above, my plot is just showing up empty. I believe i'm coding it properly and unlike the link above, I do see the that coordinates are changing over time. I'm not sure why the plot is empty.

Comment: _I do see the that coordinates are changing over time_: sounds like what you were looking for. _I'm not sure what the issue is_:If you do not describe your issue, we don't know either.

Comment: Sorry, I thought my reference to the link above would have cleared that up. I updated my post. Even though everything looks to be set up properly, my plot is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per default one pixel is either 1 point or 0.72 points (depending on whether you run the code in a jupyter notebook or as a standalone plot). If you create a plot with a markersize of `0.05`, each marker will thus have a size of `0.05` pixels or `0.07` pixels, respectively. Since it is already quite hard to see 1 pixel on a screen, especially if the alpha is set to 0.4, observing one twentieth of a pixel is simply not possible.

Solution: **Set `markersize = 5` or higher.**

A full working example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import pandas as pd

test = pd.DataFrame({"dropoff_longitude": [-72,-73,-74,-74],
                     "dropoff_latitude": [40,41,42,43]})

xlim=(-71,-75)
ylim=(39,44)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = plt.axes(xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim)
points, = ax.plot([], [],'.',alpha = 1, markersize =5)

def init():
    points.set_data([], [])
    return points,

# animation function.  This is called sequentially
def animate(i):
    x = test["dropoff_longitude"]
    y = test["dropoff_latitude"]
    points.set_data(x, y)
    return points,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=100, interval=20, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comment but that solution didn't work. I also tried to remove the alpha parameter but no luck there either.

Comment: Well thats frustrating. It still doesn't work and I'm not quite sure how to debug it anymore.

Comment: Are you by chance trying to run it in a jupyter notebook? Jupyter creates by default png images which cannot be animated. You would then of course use an interactive backend, like `%matplotlib notebook` or `%matplotlib tk`.

Comment: That did get it to show up, but my computer seems to be having trouble allowing it to animate. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you python crash at all?

Comment: You mean using this code? No. That is rather unlikely, since there is not much that can go wrong, there is little data, so no memory issues expected, and the code is rather simple. Of course python may, like any other software, crash due to other reasons that are out of control or at least not due to the code itself.